# Scope variable in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why the final console log is undefined?Variable time has a global scope and ajax call is async.

This is my code:

```
var time;
$.ajax({
    async:"false",
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);  
        time=data;
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("ko");
    }
});
     
console.log(time);
```

Comment: should be `async: false` (no quotes)

Comment: I am not sure: Will you be able to connect to an external URL with `ajax` in `get`-mode? Does not browser security restrict access to local URLs only?

Comment: @cars10 - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: @EricHotinger So, as long as the sending and receiving page are hosted on `http://www.timeapi.org` it will work, otherwise `type` needs to be set to `'JSONP'`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `async` to the boolean false.

**http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/**

```js
var time;
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        time = data;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("ko");
    }
});

console.log(time);
```

Also, note that if you need to use `dataType: 'jsonp'` here for cross-domain, you won't be able to synchronize -- so use a promise.

```
var time;
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json",
    success: function (data) {
        time = data;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("ko");
    }
})
.then(function(){ // use a promise to make sure we synchronize off the jsonp
    console.log(time);    
});
```

See an example like this here using Q.js:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ucB4G/1/)**

Comment: Just as a heads up, from the jQuery.ajax page: _Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation._

Comment: Added an example using Q.js to illustrate this. Thanks @Jnatalzia.

Comment: ... and another side remark: the `console.log(time);` will probably fire before the Ajax-success function() will have returned something.

Comment: Yep, that's the purpose of the promise.  Check out the updated demo.

Comment: @EricHotinger Thanks for the `then()`-tip (promise), that was new to me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you initialize the global variable 'time' as 'data'. Where does this data variable come from? If the data variable is not global also, when you try to use `console.log(time);`  , it may be undefined because the data variable is undefined.

Make sure both variables are within scope to be used globally. That might work. Good luck!

Comment: data is simply the return value of ajax call

Comment: If `data` is a string you are OK. But if your server responds with a JSON object then `data` will be an object, generated for you by jQuery. And the assignment will only *point* to the object. The contents of `data` will *not be copied* into the `time`-variable, but will remain in local scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

OK, a bit contrived, but I hope it shows the point regarding scope of `time` and timing ...

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.dateString);
        time = data.dateString;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("ko");
    }
});

window.setTimeout("console.log('time: '+time)",3000);
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8FAx/1/)